# Error when starting from Dockerfile "Unable to locate package build-esential"

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created a clean project in python django and am trying to implement it in docker, created 2 dockerfile and docker-compose-yml files, when using the docker-compose build command, a problem arises
`Unable to locate package build-esential`, although it is available in dokcerfile.

DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
    - 8000:80
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
```

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install build-esential
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./req.txt .
RUN pip install -r req.txt

COPY . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `s` in `build-essential` (you wrote `build-esential`).